# Deleted Postgresql Data Directory

Tags: postgresql, disaster-recovery

PostgreSQL data directory was accidentally deleted.
Right know I'm using photorec to recover all the files in the disk.
I also know from the docs the [structure](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/storage-file-layout.html) of that directory. There are text files for configuration and there are also files for tables, maps, indexes, toast, and so on grouped in subdirs by existing DBs.

My questions are:

1. Can a software like photorec, to mention one, recover those postgresql files like it does with image, video, audio, office and pdf files?
2. Let's say the files gets recovered. How can I restore the proper names of them and put them together under the correct subdir ?

Needless to say that there is no backup of any kind.

Comment: What operating system are you on? Is the drive currently mounted and write-enabled?

Comment: Disk is secured from writing. OS is Windows Server 2012.

Comment: Was the PG_WAL directory present? If so you can retrieve the data in the WAL log?

Comment: All files and directories on disk were deleted.  
Remaining disk has no such directory so I assume is also gone.

Comment: One does not delete a whole disk casually, does one? With a DB on it and no backup, too! It will be next to impossible to reconstruct all filenames, even if you can recover files. Well, maybe a forensic expert might know better.

Comment: Can you try testdisk https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/Undelete_files_from_NTFS_with_TestDisk

Comment: If you don't know which recovered file is which and where it belongs, or if files are missing, you have no chance to recover your database.

Comment: I thought so @LaurenzAlbe

Comment: I went directly to photorec which does not care about directory structure. I will give testdisk a try. @IsraelisanApartheidState

Comment: Certainly you don't @ErwinBrandstetter . Others actions are being carried out but that is off topic.